# A simple modulo arithmetic problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, vector-lattices

I slur `$z\mod L$' here to mean the only element of $\{z+nL: n\in \mathbb{Z}\}\cap [0,L).$

We are given quantities:

- $a,b, L,$
- $D_1 = (ax \mod L) + aw$,
- $D_2 = bx+bw.$

We are also given the fact:

- $D_3 =(ax + bx)\in [0,L).$, i.e. $D_3=(D_3\mod L)$

From these facts, is it possible to compute the following in terms of the given quantities?
$$D_4 = ax+bx+aw+bw= D_3+aw + bw$$

---

Here's my try:

\begin{align}
(D_1+D_2) &= ((ax \mod L) + aw + bx+bw) \\
&= ((ax \mod L)-ax+ax+bx+aw+bw)\ \\
&= ((ax \mod L)-ax)+D_4.
\end{align}

So it is enough to find $(ax \mod L)-ax,$ which I am not sure is possible.

Comment: Ok. Comments deleted then. Now I still don't really understand how you want to derive something non-trivial from the three given equalities: the first two define $D_1$ and $D_2$, they don't really carry information. The third one does carry the information that $0\leq (a+b)x <L$. That's basically all you have. Finally, what do you mean by " *is it possible to compute...*"? Do you mean compute "the" representative of that modulo $L$? And how is that question related to $D_1$ and $D_2$?

Comment: No, I mean the quantity outright. That is, if $D_3=(a+b)\cdot x \in [0,L)$ then I want $D_3+(a+b)w \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: So to be clear, you want an answer in terms of $D_1$ and $D_2$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: You don't know $x$ and $w$ but you know $a$ and $b$ is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty of that problem is that there is a **lot** of useless data. All you need is that you know $a$, $b$, and $D_2=bx+bw$.

$$D_4=D_2\left(1+\frac ab\right)$$